# XML Serialization - Multiple Elements Same Name

Tags: xml, serialization

Using C#, I am trying to serialize XML into this string:

```
<root>
            <IncludeRetElement>TxnID</IncludeRetElement>
            <IncludeRetElement>TimeCreated</IncludeRetElement>
            <IncludeRetElement>TimeModified</IncludeRetElement>
            <IncludeRetElement>EditSequence</IncludeRetElement>
            <IncludeRetElement>TxnNumber</IncludeRetElement>
            <IncludeRetElement>CustomerRef</IncludeRetElement>

</root>
```

What must my class look like? I don't believe this would work:

```
 public class Root
 {
     List<string> IncludeRetElement = new List<string>();
 }
```

When I serialize, do I need to add special arguments to the XMLSerializer object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
[XmlElement("IncludeRetElement")]
public string[] IncludeRetElement { get; set; }
```